# Analyzing asymptotic notation $\sqrt n = O(\log^2 n)$

Tags: asymptotics

I am trying to determine whether $f(n) = \sqrt n$ is in $O(g(n))$, $\Omega(g(n))$, or $\Theta(g(n))$ where $g(n) = \log^2 n$.

The answer says that only $f(n) = \Omega(g(n))$ is correct, but why isn't $f(n) = O(g(n))$ correct as well?

The formal definition is $f(n) = O(g(n))$ means $c*g(n)$ is an upper bound on $f(n)$. Thus there exists some constant $c$ such that $f(n)$ is always $\log c*g(n)$ for large enough $n$.

If we take $n = 100 \; 000$ (I think that is large enough), then

$$\begin{align*} \sqrt{100 \; 000}  &\leq c*\log^2 100 \; 000 \\
\sim 316  &\leq c*25
\end{align*}$$

Here we see there is indeed a $c$ such as $c=15$ that will satisfy the inequality. This doesn't make sense though because then by this logic there should be a $c$ that will satisfy *every* inequality. Am I interpreting the definitions wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I'll assume you're using base 10 logs and the convention $\log^2(x) := \log(x)^2$ since this accords with the numbers you're giving.

It's not true that $\sqrt{n} < 15 \log_{10}(x)^2$ for arbitrarily large $n$.  For instance let $n$ be a million.  Then the LHS is 1,000 and the RHS is $15(6)^2 = 540$.

More generally, there's no value of c that will work for all sufficiently large n, as you can see by working out the limit of $\sqrt{x}/log(x)^2$ using techniques from your calculus class.

Comment: I want to clarify and say that $log^2(x) := log(x) * log(x) := log(x)^2$ to make sure we are not thinking of different things. My intuition was if $n$ is a million, or a larger number, all you need is to keep increasing to a large enough $c$ (I believe this is flawed, but I am not sure why). When is there ever a value of c that will work for all sufficiently large n? Can't you just keep pushing n to be a larger number as  $\lim_{n\to\infty}$

Comment: You can't have c grows as n grows.  Otherwise the definition would be meaningless as every pair of functions would satisfy it. You need one value of c that works for all sufficiently large n.

Comment: Okay that's fair. That makes sense. What determines what that one value of C will be?

Comment: Well if you have one value that works, then any larger value works just as well.  Typically we don't care much about what this number is anyway; the whole point of using asymptotic notation is that we get to throw details like that away.